# Broken flash movie player! allowFullScreen does not work with anything other than a wmode value of "window" (the default)

Tags: flash, modal-dialog, fullscreen, z-index, wmode

I have a flash player on a page which plays videos. I also have modal popups (made out of div elements) which need to be able to display over the top of the flash player when they are opened, etc... I can't change either of these requirements since they are part of the spec I have been given.

Flash seems to ignore z-indexes I set on it with css, and the modal popups will therefore only appear above the video player if I set the video player's wmode to opaque or transparent. **However, if I do this then the full screen functionality stops working correctly: when I un-fullscreen the video it stays zoomed in.**

**In short**

- If you open a popup on an item page
  or another page containing flash the
  popup should be displayed above this.
- Flash ignores z-index values.
- You can stop flash ignoring z-index
  values by    setting wmode to opaque
  or    transparent rather than the
  default: window.
- **This stops full screen from working
  correctly.**

Has anybody else faced this issue before? What can I do to fix it? I was thinking of recreating the video player with wmode=opaque whenever I opened a modal popup and then switching it back to wmode=window when the modal popup is closed, since this would mean that the popup should display above it (as wmode=opaque) and the fullscreen should work correct (as wmode=window). However, this is not ideal at all: as well as being a hack it would also mean that the video would stop playing if somebody clicked a button which opened a popup.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best shot would probably be to listen for `flash.events.FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN` and when that occurs force a reset of the width and height of the Video object.

This means that you can continue to use opaque wmode.

Comment: I am not a flash developer myself. Any idea on how you could force a reset of the width and height of the video object to the size of the container it is in? From what I read in the video object API those values are read-only. Do you have any links or articles you could point me to on this? Thanks!

Comment: All of this sounds like either a bug in flash itself, or more likely the player that you are using. ´videoHeight´ and ´videoWidth´ are read-only, but ´width´ and ´height´ (inherited from DisplayObject) can be modified. Changing these might force a reset. If not, of if you cannot change the source code, the only thing I think that you can do is find another player.

Comment: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-892

Looks like I'm not the only person with this issue.